Internationalization i18N with Excel Add-in custom ribbon
I work on an Excel custom ribbon. The product is in English. Now the plan is to support multiple languages to display the custom ribbon in Excel based on Windows language setting.
I am not able to create a RC or RESX like file for the XLAM file, something like what we have for C# or C++. Also, I am unable to add multiple XML files to same XLAM. Is it not supported?
Using Office RibbonX editor I can create multiple tab ids and duplicate the menu options in all other languages. Then from VBA, based on ProductLanguageID, I call the language specific tag.
The problems that I can foresee are

The XLAM becomes huge. If English has 30 menu items. With French, Spanish it becomes a 90 items long XLAM.
Loading the big XLAM becomes unwieldy. A runtime loading of relevant XLAM (if supported) looks cleaner.

My questions are

Does Excel support RESX/RC like structure? If it does, where does it reside and which tool to use to generate it?
Can I have more than one XML file inside my XLAM, each for a language. Also, how will I call the specific XML from VBA code?

